# Accessing member function of super class

Tags: class, inheritance, abap

**How can I access a super class' method from a child class' method?**

Here is an example that illustrates the problem:
Lets say, we have two classes

```
class parent definition.
public section.
  methods f.
endclass.

class child definition inheriting from parent.
public section.
  methods f redefinition.
  methods g.
endclass.
```

Now, in the implementation of `g` we want to call the super class' implementation of `f` similar to the following syntactically wrong snippet

```
class child implementation.
  method g.
    super->f( ). "forbidden: super-> can only be used to call the previous implementation of the same method
  endmethod.
endclass.
```

As stated in the comment, it is not possible to use `super->`. Can you help?

---

After some googling, it was suggested to copy the implementation of `parent->f` into `child->g` is this really the only way to do it?

---

**The actual use case**

@vwegert asked why `f` is redefined in the first place. In my real use case, `parent` is a view, and `child` its extension. `child->f` is an event handler which is supposed to trigger a popup. `child` receives a callback when the popup closes in form of a call to `g`. If `g` is called, the original implementation `parent->f` should be called.

Comment: Why do you redefine the method in the first place...?

Comment: @vwegert I have added the actual use case to the question, however I do believe, that the general question deserves an answer, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to resort to some rather ugly workaround - like set a flag (attribute of the object) in `g`, then call the redefined `f`, check whether the flag is set and if it is, only call `super->f`. It sounds like a very broken design, though. You don't go into details, but I assume you're not able to change the parent view - otherwise I'd strongly suggest to re-think the design because this will lead to unnecessary complexity and technical debt that will very likely introduce bugs and increase maintenance cost.

Comment: @vwgert this is indeed the solution I came up with. I'll leave this question open for some more time still hoping for a better solution. I'll accept it eventually otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not mind creating a protected method `do_f` in the parent class and then delegating the control from `f` method to `do_f` method in it. Then the following solution could be quite a neat one. No code duplication, only some additional work in delegating the call in the "original" `f` method.

```
REPORT zzy.

CLASS parent DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS f.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
    METHODS do_f.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS parent IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD f.
    do_f( ).
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD do_f.
    WRITE / 'Parent''s f'.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS child DEFINITION INHERITING FROM parent.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS:
      f REDEFINITION,
      g.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS child IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD f.
    WRITE / 'Child''s f'.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD g.
    do_f( ).
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  DATA(lo_child) = NEW child( ).
  lo_child->g( ).
  lo_child->f( ).
```